# Empty PHP Contact form = 500 error

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, email

I've done quite a few contact forms before but for some reason if any field is empty then i get sent to the error 500 page saying 
"500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

The odd thing is that the form still sends, with whatever information has been entered so the submit function and asset seems to be working.

I've tried setting the variables to have a value before the form, and after the submit (adding " ".$variablename) so they aren't empty but it doesn't seem to work.  I'm using the form with instructions to fill in each field but it's for a web enquiry form so I want clients to be able to add as much or as little as they want (so don't need form validation for example).

I'm using bootstrap for the framework of the site.
 Any ideas??  Code below

HTML

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="modalContact" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="form">

        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4>Not sure what you need?</h4><p>Fill in form below as you can and we will get in touch with some suggestions.  Please ensure you fill in every field, if you're not sure, say you're not sure!</p>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

            <form action="scripts/contactscript.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Name: </label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"  name="name" placeholder="Please give us your full name">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Email: </label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Example@youremail.com">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="url" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Website:    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="If you already have a website please enter it here. Alternatively you may want to enter a link to a site that you like or feel would help us better understand your aims, this could be for content, styles or interactive sections.  Please let us know any specifics in the 'extra' section below"></span> </label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" placeholder="www.yourexample.com">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="background" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">What: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Let us know what you want from your website.  Is it a business, a blog, for fun? try and keep the description short using keywords"></span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="bkgrd" placeholder="Tell us about what you want to achieve" rows="3" id="background"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="content" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Content: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="What tools do you need your website to have? "></span></label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
                        <label class="checkbox ">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="content[]" id="contact" value="contact form">Contact form
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox ">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="content[]" id="booking" value="booking system">Booking system/interactive calender
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox ">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="content[]" id="commerce" value="ecommerce"> E-commerce/secure check out
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="content[]" id="cms" value="cms"> Content management system <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Having a content management system means users (or you) can update the website via a log on function, similar to a blog.  Without this you may need someone to update your website manually"></span>
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="content[]" id="users" value="profiles"> Secure log in/user profiles
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox ">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="content[]" id="social" value="social"> Embedded social media
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox ">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="content[]" id="none" value="none"> None
                        </label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Let us know any specific ideas you may have in mind or have discovered on other sites while browsing"></textarea>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="other" class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-sm-3">Anything else? </label>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 col-lg-9 col-sm-9">
                        <textarea id="other" name="other" class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Anything else you feel might be useful" ></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn-default" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

        </div>


    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

PHP(not on the same page)

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "noreply@mywebsite.com";
    $subject = "Website Enquiry";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $bkgrd = $_POST['bkgrd'];
    $content = implode(": ", $_POST['content']);
    $other = $_POST['other'];


}

$sub2 = "Thank you for your enquiry";
$msg= "Thank you for your enquiry.  We have received your contact form and will be in touch soon to discuss this further\n


Thanks\n

;


$message = "From:  $name\n Email: $email\n URL: $url\n Overview: $bkgrd\n Content: $content \n Other: $other   ";

mail($email, $sub2, $msg);

if(mail($to, $subject, $message)){

    header("location: http://www.mywebsite.com");


}else{


    header("location: http://www.mywebsite.com");
}
```

Comment: error 500 is an internal server error, so you php code is probaly off, a good way to fix these errors is through the error log on the server you are running it on.

Comment: @MartinHenriksen but... but.... that means to look at the error log file! The _error log file_! Argh! You want people to actually read about their error? What about the fun game of guessing for hours?

Comment: I think you have missed this  `"` on `$msg` variable declaration.

Comment: hey thanks, i've looks through the error logs but doesn't seem to reveal very much.

Comment: Put this: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` above all your code and tell me what error it gives you.

Comment: @tom - just comes up with the same 500 message.  the log file sys :

Comment: 2016-02-13 15:22:55 W3SVC451 N1NWVPWEB013 188.121.43.36 POST /scripts/contactscript.php - 80 - 82.0.113.13 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_11_3)+AppleWebKit/601.4.4+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/9.0.3+Safari/601.4.4 - http://mywebsite/contact.php myemail.co.uk 500 0 0 1410 544 109